# How to avoid IntegrityError issue with update_or_create?

Tags: python, django

I would appreciate it if someone could explain why I'm having `IntegrityError` exception being thrown here, and how to avoid it.

When an object already exists, isn't the `update_or_create` method supposed to update it ?

**models.py**

```
class OHLCV(TimestampedModel):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candles', null=True)
    index = models.ForeignKey(Index, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candles', null=True)
    timeframe = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    open, high, low, close, volume = [models.FloatField(null=True) for i in range(5)]
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "OHLCV"
        unique_together = [['market', 'timeframe', 'datetime'],
                           ['index', 'timeframe', 'datetime']]
```

**tasks.py**

```
@app.task
def bulk_update_ohlcv(timeframe):
    for obj in Market.objects.filter(active=True):
        if obj.exchange.is_status_ok():
            update_ohlcv.delay('market', obj.pk, timeframe)


@app.task
def update_ohlcv(self, type, pk, timeframe):

    [code here]
    if obj.__class__ == Market:
        ohlcv, created = OHLCV.objects.update_or_create(market=obj,
                                                        timeframe=timeframe,
                                                        datetime=dt,
                                                        open=candle[1],
                                                        defaults=defaults
                                                        )

    elif obj.__class__ == Index:
        ohlcv, created = OHLCV.objects.update_or_create(index=obj,
                                                        timeframe=timeframe,
                                                        datetime=dt,
                                                        open=candle[1],
                                                        defaults=defaults
                                                        )
```

Error:

```
-celery_worker-1  | 2023-04-01T06:55:47.710298043Z IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
-celery_worker-1  | 2023-04-01T06:55:47.710302260Z "market_ohlcv_market_id_timeframe_datetime_8ffd84de_uniq"
-celery_worker-1  | 2023-04-01T06:55:47.710306227Z DETAIL:  Key (market_id, timeframe, datetime)=(84, 5m, 2023-03-31 21:20:00+00) 
-celery_worker-1  | 2023-04-01T06:55:47.710310646Z already exists.
```

Comment: I think, you are getting error because of two tasks trying to create OHLCV object with the same values and the same time and it causes race condition

Comment: @mirodil when I run only one task it still throws the IntegrytiError exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with the `open` field being in the kwargs of the `update_or_create`.
Django will try to get an `OHLCV` matching the four fields `market`, `timeframe`, `datetime` and `open`. If there is a instance matching the first three and not `open`, Django will create a new instance clashing with your constraint.

You'll need to either move the `open` field to the default dictionnary or include it in the unique together constraint

Comment: Thank you I scratched my head hours with this one